# wrong friendly url in liferay

Tags: url, mapping, liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to create a friendly url for my portlet. This is my original url:

```
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/memories?p_p_id=blogscustomportlet_WAR_blogscustomportlet&_blogscustomportlet_WAR_blogscustomportlet_action=viewEntry&entryId=271101
```

I'm using this configuration:

```
<routes>
    <route>
        <pattern>/add</pattern>
        <implicit-parameter name="action">viewEntry</implicit-parameter>
        <implicit-parameter name="p_p_id">blogscustomportlet_WAR_blogscustomportlet</implicit-parameter>
        <implicit-parameter name="p_p_lifecycle">0</implicit-parameter>
        <implicit-parameter name="p_p_state">normal</implicit-parameter>
        <implicit-parameter name="p_p_mode">view</implicit-parameter>
    </route>
</routes>
```

and get this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/memories/-/blog/add&entryId=271101
```

The first parameter separator is '&' and not '?'

Comment: what do you mean by get this url? I think you should use a url like -/blog/add/271101 or -/blog/add/entryId=271101 and generate parameter from url into route file

Comment: Could you update your question with how you are generating the URL? And which 6 release you're on.

Comment: hi Adi thanks, how can i generate parameter from url? what is the configuration i need write into route file?

Comment: can i use {entryId:\d+} for get entryId value?